# ORACLE SQL, If statement to detect datatype of a parameter from a function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a function that has a variable of any data type passed in. I want to be able to do a if statement to see if it is a varchar2 or a number.

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_manager(pass in sys.ANYDATA )
    RETURN varchar2
    IS T1 varchar2(300);

    I_var varchar2(300);
    I_num number;

    F_NAME STRING(300);
    L_NAME STRING(300);    
BEGIN

    if pass%type = I_var%type  then --Name
         F_NAME := REGEXP_SUBSTR(PASS, '(\S*)(\s)'); --First Word
         L_NAME := REGEXP_SUBSTR(PASS, '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2); --Second Word

         select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME ||  ' ' || PHONE_NUMBER INTO T1 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME = F_NAME AND EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME = L_NAME ;
    elsif pass%type = I_num%type then --ID Number
         select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME || ' ' || PHONE_NUMBER INTO T1 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID = pass;

    end if;

    RETURN(T1);
END;
```

I get these compiler errors:

```
Error(12,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(12,13): PLS-00208: identifier 'TYPE' is not a legal cursor attribute
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are on Oracle 12.2, you could use the function, VALIDATE_CONVERSION, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amitabh said, the `getTypeName` function is the most important part.  But there are lots of tricky parts involved with the ANY* types.

For example, it would be incredibly difficult to find the type of a local variable.  Probably the best bet would be to use PL/SCOPE, but that's a lot of work.  Since the variable must be hard-coded to assign to it, the below code also hard-codes the local variable type name for the comparison.

In practice you almost never want to use the ANY types.  They are great for solving some hard problems.  But you don't want to build a framework around them if you can avoid it.  It's usually better to generate lots of simple code, or to generate dynamic SQL.

### Function

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_manager(pass in sys.ANYDATA )
    RETURN varchar2
    IS T1 varchar2(300);

    I_var varchar2(300);
    I_num number;

    F_NAME varchar2(300);
    L_NAME varchar2(300);    

    V_STATUS pls_integer;
BEGIN
    if PASS.getTypeName = 'SYS.VARCHAR2' then --Name
         V_STATUS := PASS.GetVarchar2(F_NAME);
         V_STATUS := PASS.GetVarchar2(L_NAME);
         F_NAME := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(F_NAME, '(\S*)(\s)')); --First Word
         L_NAME := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(L_NAME, '(\s)(\S*)')); --Second Word

         select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME ||  ' ' || PHONE_NUMBER INTO T1 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME = F_NAME AND EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME = L_NAME ;
    elsif PASS.getTypeName = 'SYS.NUMBER' then --ID Number
         V_STATUS := PASS.GetNumber(I_NUM);
         select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME || ' ' || PHONE_NUMBER INTO T1 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID = I_NUM;
    end if;

    RETURN(T1);
END;
/
```

### Sample Schema

```
--drop table employees;
create table employees(employee_id number, first_name varchar2(300), last_name varchar2(300), phone_number varchar2(300));

insert into employees values(1, 'JOHN', 'SMITH', '867-5309');
commit;
```

### Results

```
select get_manager(anydata.ConvertVarchar2('JOHN SMITH')) employee_data from dual;

EMPLOYEE_DATA
-------------
JOHN SMITH 867-5309

select get_manager(anydata.ConvertNumber(1)) employee_data from dual;

EMPLOYEE_DATA
-------------
JOHN SMITH 867-5309
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use GETTYPENAME function here to get the data type.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/t_anydat.htm#i1000030

Thanks,
Amitabh